# WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 4 (SIGILL).',)

Tags: celery

cellery version 4.0.2
celery -A rare worker -Q mm --loglevel=info

also i have tried

REMAP_SIGTERM=SIGQUIT celery -A rare worker -Q mm --loglevel=info

[2017-06-16 11:20:15,457: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: rare.tasks.process_audio_chunk[84b8c566-48b4-4e20-a916-07d8f59c09a4]
[2017-06-16 11:20:15,473: INFO/PoolWorker-6] Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.10.99.5
[2017-06-16 11:20:17,674: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'PoolWorker-6' pid:9933 exited with 'signal 4 (SIGILL)'
[2017-06-16 11:20:17,685: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 4 (SIGILL).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/deploy/Envs/rare_management/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1224, in mark_as_worker_lost
human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 4 (SIGILL).

Comment: After a long Timetravel I have found that in my celery task function code was broken (ie sys.exit(0)) which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to code was exiting, in my celery task due to numpy version. Updated numpy and works fine.